# Joomla breadcrumb showing "Uncategorized" category

Tags: php, joomla, breadcrumbs

I have a menu that link to a "single article" in Joomla.

So, the breadcrumb is: Home > Services

Now, I created a article to put into service page. For exemple a "Development service" page.

So, I went to "Services" page and create a link to this page, now the bradcrumb is: Home > Services > Uncategorised > Development service

How to put only Home > Services > Development service

Are there some tricks?

Comment: Haven't ever encountered this, and can't find a way around it if there is away.  I see there are a number of extensions at http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-navigation that might help out though.

Comment: My version is Joomla 2.5

Comment: I done this changing the core files, but it would better if don't change the core files.

Comment: Looks like thats the only way - my answer has a link about how to do it without interfering with future updates to the core.

Answer (score 3):

Found some workarounds for you at the [Joomla Forum](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=722773&view=previous), but with consideration as described in [How to override the component mvc from the Joomla! core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core).  This actually hides the category in the breadcrumb, but could be easily adapted to do so only if `$this->item->catid` is 0.

The change you want is in :`components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php`

```
$category = JCategories::getInstance('Content')->get($this->item->catid);
while ($category && ($menu->query['option'] != 'com_content' || $menu->query['view'] == 'article' || $id != $category->id) && $category->id > 1)
{
    $path[] = array('title' => $category->title, 'link' => ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($category->id));
    $category = $category->getParent();
}
```

Comment: Was exactly what I do. Thank you. I really think that doesn't exist other solution...

Comment: Awesome post - explained a lot -helped me to learn more about Joomla

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and spent an hour to google the issue. If you have assigned single article in 2 or more menus that can be happend :) remove menus and assign all articles again.